# Control fan speed

Tags: temperature, fancontrol

My laptop works fine in Ubuntu but temperatures are higher than the rare cases I use Windows.

If there a way to tell Ubuntu to turn the fan on earlier?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64 on a Toshiba R830 laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fans are normally controlled by the hardware in response to temperature, so you don't need to worry about it -- if the system gets too warm, it will speed up the fans automatically.

You may be able to setup lm-sensors to detect the fan controller and the `fancontrol` package to take over, but this is not easy nor a good idea.  You would start with running `sensors-detect` to see if it can detect any recognized chips and setup the driver for it.